# Handling division by zero axiomatically

Tags: functions, logic, real-numbers

Suppose we define the multiplicative inverse function on real numbers as follows:

$\forall{x \in \mathbb{R}}(x \neq 0 \implies x \times \frac{1}{x} = 1)  $.

Consider this truth table.
\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c||c|}
\hline
x \neq 0 & x \times \frac{1}{x} = 1 & x \neq 0 \implies x \times \frac{1}{x} = 1 \\ \hline
T & T & T  \\ 
T & F & F  \\ 
F & T & T  \\ 
F & F & T  \\ \hline
\end{array}

If the implication always holds we know that there will be a case when $x = 0$ and $x \times \frac{1}{x} = 1$ is true!  This seems to fly in the face of common sense.  Is this the correct way to handle division axiomatically?

Comment: When $x\neq 0$ we don't even need to check the "implied" statement. So no, we don't "know there will be a case" such as you describe.

Comment: Consider for simplicity $\mathbb Q$ : in this way, having $x=p/q, p,q \in \mathbb N$, we are able to compute $1/x$. The formula is : $\forall x \in \mathbb Q \exists y \in \mathbb Q (x = 0 \lor xy=1)$. We have to "check" **all** $x \in \mathbb Q$ : *i)* for $x=0$, the formula inside the quantifiers is satisfied ($TRUE \lor p \equiv TRUE$); *ii)* for $x \ne 0$ we have $x=p/q$, and thus it is enough to choose $y=q/p$ and the "inner" formula is again satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't conclude that there will be such a case. Simply knowing that the implication holds means that we will always find ourselves in one of the lines of the truth table that ends with T. It does not mean that *each* of those three lines has to occur in practice.

As long as the line that ends with F does *not* occur, it doesn't matter whether it's all the others that occur, or only some of them.

The axiom taken in itself certainly *allows* for a model where $0\times \frac10=1$. But there are (or should be) other axioms that reject such a model.

Comment: Perhaps as a results of edits, it is unclear what your first sentence "No, you can't conclude that" refers to.

Comment: @Rob: Clearer now?

Comment: Yes, your edit has clarified that part of your answer. However, I don't understand your proposal to introduce other axioms that prevent certain undesirable models, if you are working in the context of classical first order logic where $\frac{1}{0}$ has to denote something.

Comment: @RobArthan: I'm not proposing extra axioms specifically to ensure $0\times\frac10\ne1$ -- this would be a consequence of other axioms that we want for other purposes. In particular, the usual laws of artihmetic imply $\forall x(0\times x=0)$ so if we also have $1\ne 0$ from somewhere it will follow that $0\times\frac10\ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

First of all, if $x=0$ and $x\times\frac1x=1$, the implication is true, but that does not mean that a value for $x$ that satisfies both of these conditions exists. So this conclusion doesn't necessarily invalidate your operation.

However, you may want to *ensure* that such a value for $x$ can't exist. To do this, you could specify that $x\ne0 \Longleftrightarrow x\times\frac1x$ instead of the one-way implication.

Answer (score 0):

[If you look at this link on constructing real numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Synthetic_approach) It looks like the correct axiom is:

For every $x \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}$, There exists an element $x^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $x * x^{-1} = 1$.

This shows the existence of a multiplicative inverse, only if $x \neq 0$, thus division by zero will never happen.